# Import last excel worksheet to another workbook as first worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, import, worksheet

I have two excel files, one with multiple excel worksheet with each month as worksheet name, for month Aug, it will have 8 worksheets, for Oct it will have 10 worksheets and so on. The other excel which is the excel file that I'm working on it, i need to import last worksheet from the monthly excel file into this excel as the first worksheet because there are macro code need it to be in first worksheet.

In short, import duplicate/'create new copy' of last sheet (worksheet name always change) to another workbook as first worksheet.

```
Dim wbCopy As Workbook
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range
Dim wbPaste As Workbook
Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
Dim rngPaste As Range

Set wbPaste = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open("O:\abc\Inventory\Monthly.xlsm") 
Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'Question- how to always select last worksheet?
Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range("a:aa").EntireColumn  'Question- can i duplicate a copy of worksheet ?
Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Worksheets("Order Quantities")  
Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range("a1")  'Question- this just paste into "Order Quantities", but how to move or duplicate the worksheet into first worksheet in excel workbook. ?

rngCopy.Copy
rngPaste.PasteSpecial

Workbooks.Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("Monthly.xlsm").Close False
```

Comment: Two questions, do you need to import the sheet, or the data on this last sheet? If the first, which name will it be given on the new workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets.count will give you the index of the last worksheet in the queue.

```
dim wbPaste  as workbook

Set wbPaste = ActiveWorkbook

with Workbooks.Open("O:\abc\Inventory\Monthly.xlsm", readonly:=true) 

    .workSheets(.Worksheets.count).Copy Before:=wbPaste.Sheets(1)
    .close savechanges:=false

end with

'optionally rename the new imported worksheet
wbPaste.workSheets(1).name = "abc"
```

Comment: It works but one minor changes as below. From Before:=wbPaste.workSheets(1) to Before:=wbPaste.Sheets(1). This ensures it is pasted to the 1st sheet of all other worksheets including individual chart sheets.

Comment: thank you very much for help in resolving this. thanks